# Changing a cookie doesn't affect it until the next Request - how to fix this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpmodule

I am familiar with Microsoft's "best practices" for handling the life-cycle of a cookie (as defined on MSDN), and am following these, but have found an odd scenario that I need to fix.  I can't imagine I'm the first to experience this, so wanted to see what the community's take on this was.

By the way, one obvious fix for what I am about to describe would be to force a re-direct, but for reasons I won't go into, a 302 is not an option.

Okay, so I receive a WebRequest and in that I have a specific cookie.  Depending on the flow, I need to "remove" this cookie.  To do this, I set the Response Cookie's value to null and set its expiration date to sometime last year.

However, later on, a very separate part of the code attempts to re-read the cookie and - guess what - it finds the old value.  **Note**: this is still part of the SAME web-request, we've not yet returned to the client.

When we return to the Client's browser, the cookie is duly removed.

One solution I have is that, at the very beginning of the web-request, I copy the Request cookies into a separate NameValueCollection.

- Every time I update a cookie value, I update both the cookie in the Response.Cookies collection, and I update the value in my separate NameValueCollection.
- Everytime I delete a cookie, I expire the cookie in the Response.Cookies collection, and I remove it from the NameValueCollection
- Every time I add a new cookie, I add it to both the Response.Cookies collection and my NameValueCollection.
- Whenever I want to read a cookie's value, I read it from my NameValueCollection.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Griff

Comment: This is expected behavior. Since web request is still getting processed and control haven't returned back to client cookie will not get removed until next request is fired. Also if you check HttpRequest.Cookies property its readonly that means once you receive request you can not modify that collection but what can be modified is Response.Cookies and those modified cookies will come into play when next request is fired.

Comment: Hi Pankaj - thanks for the response.  So, based on the fact I have to handle this, is there a preferred way to do this (other than the solution I've mentioned)?

Comment: Since I am not aware of exact scenario and how its implemented I may not be able to judge proposed solution in detail however at surface level it looks good.

Comment: Okay - changed the approach and now when I want to read a cookie, I first check if the Resonse.Cookies.AnyKeys contains my Cookie Name.  If it does, then I read from the Response cookies.  If it doesn't then I read from the Request cookies.  I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first check if the Resonse.Cookies.AnyKeys contains my Cookie Name. If it does, then I read from the Response cookies. If it doesn't then I read from the Request cookies.